# Why discovered device is always named "BLE client"?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know it is not that important question. I am trying out the Bluetooth low energy to discover devices, query for services, and transmit information. I got success in discovering devices. My question is no matter what the Bluetooth device name is, in the bluetoothDevice.getName() always gives me the name "BLE client". Any idea how to change this name? or how to get the device name? is there anything I am missing?

```
private ScanCallback scanCallBack = new ScanCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG, result.getDevice().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results)
    {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode)
    {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
    }
};
```